# Expected value of a binary decimal generated by coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

A coin is flipped infinitely many times. Heads is $1$, tails is $0$. The string created by the heads and tails is turned into its respective string of ones and zeros.

If I write $1.$ before the binary string it creates a decimal in base 2.
I've been trying to figure out the expected value of the aforementioned decimal in base 10. So far, I have that the number generated, $N$, can be represented by $$N=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{X(\omega)}{2^n}\right)$$ where $X(\omega)$ is a random variable such that $$X(\omega)= 
\begin{cases}
1, \text{if $\omega = heads$} \\
0, \text{if $\omega = tails$} \\
\end{cases}$$
but I have no idea where to go from here. Am I going down the wrong path, or is this line of reasoning correct? How can I find the expected value that N will be?

Comment: Please don't take it amiss, but I have rolled back your edit. Siddharth Bhat's answer is already there, in its proper place. You have accepted it, so everybody can see that you are happy with it! If you look around this site, you will see that this is how things are done here.

Comment: Understood. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By linearity of expectation, we know that $\mathbb E[X + Y] = \mathbb E [X] + \mathbb E[Y]$.
2. We know that $\mathbb E [c] = c$ where c is a constant.
3. By linearity of expectation, we know that $\mathbb E[\alpha X] = \alpha \mathbb E[X]$ where $\alpha$ is a constant and $X$ is a random variable.

Using these, we can compute the expectation of your sum as:

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb E[N] = \\
&\mathbb E\left[1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty X(\omega)/2^n\right] =  \\
&\mathbb E\left[1 \right] + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E \left[ X(\omega)/2^n\right] =\\
&1 +   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \ \mathbb E \left[ X(\omega) \right] =\\
&1 +  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \\
&1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \\
&1 + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} \right) = \\
&1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{3}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Just fixed it :)

Comment: @Robert: Could you please refresh? It should render correctly now.

Comment: Thank you — much appreciated. I'll edit my post with your answer included.

Comment: Something wrong here: you have a running index of $i$ but $n$ in the formulas

Comment: But the expected value is obviously $\frac32$, because the numbers generate a uniform distribution on $[1,2]$. So you've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I see it now: $\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}$ is $1$, not $\frac12$.

Comment: Oh gosh, yes. I just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Right, @TonyK, I looked at the picture for expansions of length $1$ and $2$, and decided that the expectation should be $\frac32$, too.